# Default syntax groups use colors >=16

Tags: syntax-highlighting, colorscheme, color

I have few quetion about color scheme and terminals... The web is plenty of posts about it but I still does not understand the following:

After a fresh install of (g)vim on arch, I did a

```
$ vim new_file
```

then in vim I did

```
:highlight
```

which result in several groups (the ones in :h highlight-default). More interestingly, they used colors that are not in my 16 terminals colors. I can see for instance

> Folded ... ctermbg=82 ...

and the color shows the color number 82 of my terminal (confirmed with a printf "\033[48;5;82mTEST\n").

On the other side I have a minimal vimrc which only contain **set t_CO=16** after the *runtime! archlinux.vim*. I also run vim inside urxvt-unicode where I put my funny 16 colors in the *.Xressources*. Also echo $TERM says "rxvt-unicode" without "-256color".

**I don't understand why vim use these colors >=16 by default.**

Comment: You might be interested in work/discussion on https://github.com/vim/colorschemes

Comment: Thanks for pointing to me these works/discussions. I will take a deeper look. Nevertheless this does not explain the behavior I explained since I am "syntax off" and :scriptnames doesnot loaded any of colorscheme related file. More interestingly, I open vim on tty2 (I am not specialist here about vocabulary) but in this case Folded group fall backs to ctermfg=6. In fact all colors are between 0 to 7. How can Obtain such behaviour with urxvt....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rxvt` is recognized as 88-color terminal, so Vim makes use of several codes below 88.

See [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/776b954622b45125dfdcb4a61243ca90956b0825/src/highlight.c#L496) and below.

Comment: Very Nice! And thanks. Do you agree that :h cterm-colors should be updated?

Comment: @Airwan No, I don't see what's wrong with them. Could you elaborate?

Comment: My mistake! I was confused with keywords used in colorscheme that I though doesn't point to the right color but it is not. 
But setting t_Co=16 it would be nice to use color_number_16() instead of 88... I don't really understand the choice of assuming urxvt to be 88-colors terminal :o

Comment: @Airwan If you have `set t_Co=16` then all cterm colors must be under 16.

Comment: Waaaw t_Co vs t_CO! I am so stupid... but a little less now :o